# netDxf package - System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common

Tags: c#, dxf

I am attempting to run the code sample listed on the README for the netDXF project: https://github.com/haplokuon/netDxf, but the code throws the following exception on the line `DxfDocument dxf = new DxfDocument();`:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Steps I followed:
1. I installed Visual Studio 2019 and created a new project with a "target Framework" value of ".NET core 3.0" and an "Output Type" of "Console application".
2. I have installed the netDXF package by right-clicking my project and selecting "Manage NuGet Packages", and installing netDxf from there.
3. I ran the code, saw the exception, and gathered the following stack trace from the .netDxf library:

```
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.Tables.TextStyle.TextStyle(string name, string font, bool checkName)  Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.Tables.TextStyle.TextStyle(string name, string font)  Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.Tables.TextStyle.Default.get()    Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.DxfDocument.AddDefaultObjects()   Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.DxfDocument.DxfDocument(netDxf.Header.HeaderVariables drawingVariables, bool createDefaultObjects, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string> supportFolders) Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.DxfDocument.DxfDocument(netDxf.Header.HeaderVariables drawingVariables)   Unknown
    netDxf.dll!netDxf.DxfDocument.DxfDocument() Unknown
>   Mason.dll!Mason.Program.Main() Line 15  C#
```

Here is the full code snippet that I am attempting to run (Program.cs):

```
using netDxf;
using netDxf.Entities;
using netDxf.Header;

namespace Mason
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // your dxf file name
            string file = "sample.dxf";

            // by default it will create an AutoCad2000 DXF version
            DxfDocument dxf = new DxfDocument();
            // an entity
            Line entity = new Line(new Vector2(5, 5), new Vector2(10, 5));
            // add your entities here
            dxf.AddEntity(entity);
            // save to file
            dxf.Save(file);

            // this check is optional but recommended before loading a DXF file
            bool isBinary;
            DxfVersion dxfVersion = DxfDocument.CheckDxfFileVersion(file, out isBinary);
            // netDxf is only compatible with AutoCad2000 and higher DXF version
            if (dxfVersion < DxfVersion.AutoCad2000) return;
            // load file
            DxfDocument loaded = DxfDocument.Load(file);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a .NETFramework library, requires targeting at least 4.5.  You did something to get it working in a .NETCore project, that did not work out well.  You can't omit an important detail like that.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like that is the issue. I created a .NETCore project, but netDxf depends on the .NETFramework.

I installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/netDXF/, but when I created a new .NETFramework project rather than a .NETCore project I installed https://www.nuget.org/packages/netDxf.netstandard/, and now the code works.

If you would like to post your response as the answer to the question, I will happily accept it as the asnwer.