# I get an exception when I instantiate a WebBrowser Control in my F# app

Tags: .net-core, f#, windows-forms-core

I am trying to instantiate a WebBrowser control within my F# application:

```
open System;;
open System.Net.Http;;
open System.Windows.Forms;;
...
let browser =
    new WebBrowser(ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true,
                   Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                   DocumentText = fsharpOrg.Result)
```

But I get this exception:

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Drawing.Common**, Version=6.0.0.0,...
```

I am using dotnet sdk version 6.0.100. I have searched for answers or similar problems in forums and documentation, but I have not found something that can lead me to the fix. Any insight we'll be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the DLL for System.Drawing.Common in your output folder? so both the result of your code and the DLL is in the same folder.

Comment: Why do you have semicolons at the end of the open statements? I don't think they're needed.

Comment: I have compiled your code in a small test application, and I don't have this problem. I have the 6.0.100 and 6.0.101 SDKs installed, and also a bunch of older. Is there some other library you're using that tries to pull in System.Drawing.Common in a different version than what the app itself wants?

Comment: Are you referencing System.Drawing.Common in the project file? I [don't think you're supposed to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58617052/netdxf-package-system-io-filenotfoundexception-could-not-load-file-or-assemb) in .NET 6.

Comment: @BentTranberg, 1.- Have the semicolons because I ported the program to an FSI script for debugging 2.- I added this directive before all the code: #r "C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App\6.0.0\System.Windows.Forms.dll" because the environment could not find the reference to the winforms libraries 3.- The extent of my knowledge is that I am not referencing that dll explicitly, but I am not 100% sure.

Comment: Did you try to build a project from scratch with that piece of code, just to see if that can reveal where things go wrong?

Comment: thanks @BentTranberg for your help!

Comment: thanks @LosManos for your help too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `#r` in code, use it only in script files.

Error occurs because runtime tries to find `System.Drawing.Common` inside output folder, e.g. `bin/debug/net6.0/`, but not in `C:/Program Files/dotnet/shared/...`

To fix error you should:

1. create project file,
2. add `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>` into `<PropertyGroup>`, so project will look like this:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.Net.SDK">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <OutputType>winexe<OutputType>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms> <!-- all magic in this line -->
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

3. MSBuild will resolve all necessary references and you will be able to run program

Comment: thanks! It looks like a step forward, now I get this error:

"error NETSDK1136: The target platform must be set to Windows (usually by including '-windows' in the TargetFramework property)"

and when I change the TargetFramework to net6.0-windows I get this error:

error FS0010: Unexpected start of structured construct in definition. Expected '=' or other token.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, the last errors I posted are errors in my library code, it is no longer a namespace reference problem, my bad. It seams that this changes worked :). Thanks @JL0PD for your help!